# angularJS watch received data from socket

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-app

I have need to listen to data comming frome a socket.
Chrome fires this function:

```
chrome.sockets.tcp.onReceive.addListener(function(info) {
    console.log(info);
});
```

I want my angular controll to get that info.
if i do this:

```
chrome.sockets.tcp.onReceive.addListener(function(info) {
    $scope.$broadcast("newData", info.data);
});

$scope.$on("newData", function (event, data){
    console.log(data);
    $scope.text = data;
});
```

the text model dosen't get updated.

**Is there a way to get the cycle updating and not using the apply function?**

I tried using $watch but i dident succeed.

Comment: Have you tried `$scope.$apply()`? Why would you not want to use that?

Comment: Because is still blocks the cycle and the i will need to add it to some other functions.
unless that is the correct way and there is no other.

Comment: apply is *the* way to update the view. What do you mean when you say it blocks?, couldn't you add it to a `$timeout(function () { $scope.text = data; });` and have it execute "as soon as it can" instead?

Comment: adding the timeout diden't make it work on the first call, after that it did.

Answer (score 0):

If you alter where you are saving the data the binding will work as expected. Instead of updating a property on the $scope object go one level deeper.

```
$scope.values.text = data;
```

Be sure to update your controller to include the values object creation.

```
// in controller
$scope.values = {
  data: ''
};
```